# How to use regular expressions to find the Latex expression in a string

Tags: java, regex, latex

```
private static final String TEXT = "this a test 1: $\\$$,test 2: $\\underline{\\rm defund}$, test 3:$$\\underline{\\rm defund}$$";
```

Others told me a python pattern:

```
re.compile(r'(?=([^\\]?))(?:(?P<bound2>\$\$)|\$)(.*?[^\\])(?:(?(bound2)\$\$|\$))', re.S)
```

Expected:

```
$\$$ or \$, $\underline{\rm defund}$ or \underline{\rm defund}
```

But I use it in android,Java doesn't support `express pattern`.Who can write a `Java Pattern` for me or give me some tips?

Comment: Taking a look to [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 2):

In java, there are just little modifications.

> **1.** Escape the backslash surrounding $
>
> **2.** Make use of double quotation mark

Your new code would now look like this

```
Pattern.compile("(?=([^\\]?))(?:(?P<bound2>\\$\\$)|\\$)(.*?[^\\])(?:(?(bound2)\\$\\$|\\$))");
```

Note: Make sure you import your pattern class

Comment: I know the two tips,I have tried compile it. 

java.util.regex.Pattern failed:

    Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 64
    (?=([^\]?))(?:(?P<bound2>\$\$)|\$)(.*?[^\])(?:(?(bound2)\$\$|\$))
                                                                ^
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2548)

I